# VS 2019 - What does "Run selected code locally" do?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[image]

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 ver 16.1.6 and see the first menu item in the right click menu that says "Run selected code locally".

Highlighting code and choosing this feature does not seem to do anything. My guess is that it is to do with the new Live Share Session (?). Googling the phrase surprisingly does not return any meaningful results or documentation (at least at this time).

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I also wonder what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is associated with "Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics" extension being installed.

There is still no further information about what it does to warrant being the first item on the Asp.net project text editor right click drop-down.

Here is a link to a closed bug story. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/557252/right-clicking-in-code-editor-puts-run-selected-co.html

Answer (score 0):

It should be only associated with "Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics" extension and when you are opening a Stream Analytics script file (*.asaql). This issue has been fixed in the latest extension version 2.4.2000.0. Can you update the extension and have a try?

Comment: Thanks for the update @jie_su, that removed the entry!